# Does Visual Studio for Mac support debugging iOS app with Distribution profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

[image]I am able to debug iOS app (developed in Xamarin.iOS) with Distribution profile. However Xcode does not support debugging with Distribution profile. As per Apple docs debugging is not supported via distribution profile. How is Visual Studio supporting this ? Is this an expected behaviour ?

[image]

Comment: In fact ,it is impossible that debug iOS app (developed in Xamarin.iOS) with Distribution profile(both VS and Xcode).So, can you provide more details about what you did(the steps you debug)?

Comment: I am able to debug using Distribution profile in Visual Studio, although I need to tap on the application to get it launched. But using the same profile in Xcode its denies me the app launch request. Attaching the screenshots for reference.

Comment: What additional information do you need ?

Comment: You debug your app on real device?

Comment: Yes on iPhone 7 plus

Comment: the VS said cannot start the application in the  image that you provided

Comment: Yes, but on tapping the app icon from the iPhone it launches the application and I am able to debug using breakpoints. But in case of Xcode it is not allowing to run it in debug mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179732/discussion-between-lucasz-and-subin272).

Comment: @LucasZ Hey Lucaz, any update on this ? could you please upvote the question so that it gets noticed.

Comment: Tomorrow I will discuss this issue with my colleagues

Comment: Please look at my update answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clear distinction between `Debug` and `Release` in Xcode. However, in the VS,`Debug` and `Release` just  two  configurations predefined by the system.
You can change the settings  as shown in the image below . `Right click your project->options`.
[image]
[image]

That is to say, it has nothing to do with your certificate(distribution or development).You can view it as product feature .

Comment: So basically if we enable debugging it will work regardless of the certificate in VS. Thanks for updating.